# Arrays of Object test but not getting any output

Tags: java, arrays, class, object

I would like some guidance on this particular code that I am testing but currently it is not printing out anything and on top of that I feel as if it isn't reading the text file at all. It seems to finish right away with no errors and I only get prompted that "build is successful." 
The assignment is to read from a data text file that list 20 lines of student information, each line is comprised of first name, last name, and their grade all seperated by spaces. I am put to it into an array and output their information, but for now I am testing to see if it will output the first name before I proceed.

```
public class studentClass {
private String studentFName, studentLName;
private int testScore;
private char grade;

//constructor
public studentClass(String stuFName, String stuLName, int stuTestScore){
    studentFName = stuFName;
    studentLName = stuLName;
    testScore = stuTestScore;
}

public String getStudentFName(){
    return studentFName;
}

public String getStudentLName(){
    return studentLName;
}

public int getTestScore(){
    return testScore;
}

public char getGrade(){
    return grade;
}

public void setStudentFName(String f){
    studentFName = f;
}

public void setStudentLName(String l){
    studentLName = l;
}

public void setTestScore(int t){
    if (t>=0 && t<=100){
    testScore = t;
    }
}

public void setGrade(char g){
    grade = g;
}
}
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    int numberOfLines = 20; 
    studentClass[] studentObject = new studentClass[numberOfLines];

    for(int i = 0; i>studentObject.length; i++){
        System.out.print(studentObject[i].getStudentFName());
    }

}
public static studentClass[] readStudentData(studentClass[] studentObject)throws IOException{
    //create FileReader and BufferedReader to read and store data
    FileReader fr = new FileReader("/Volumes/PERS/Data.txt");
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader (fr);

    String lines = null;
    int i = 0;

    //create array to store data for firstname, lastname, and score
    while ((lines = br.readLine()) != null){
       String stuArray[] = lines.split(" ");
       String stuFName = stuArray[0];
       String stuLName = stuArray[1];
       int score = Integer.parseInt(stuArray[2]);
       studentObject[i] = new studentClass (stuFName, stuLName, score);
       i++;
    }

    return studentObject;
}
```

Comment: I don't see the line where you actually use method readStudentData().

Comment: Thank you, after so many revisions and playing with different logic of the code, I forgot to add it.

Answer (score 1):

You need to actually call the method to read in the data. Try the following (note I didn't handle the Exception. I leave that as an exercise to you)

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    int numberOfLines = 20; 
    studentClass[] studentObject = new studentClass[numberOfLines];
    readStudentData(studentObject);

    //NOTE I CHANGED THE '>' TO '<'
    for(int i = 0; i < studentObject.length; i++){
        System.out.print(studentObject[i].getStudentFName());
    }
}

//Note that I changed the return type to void
public static void readStudentData(studentClass[] studentObject)throws IOException{
    //Your code here
```

You'll see I changed your  readStudentData to return void since you're passing the array into the method you don't need to return it. You'll need to remove the `return` at the end of it.

You could also leave it as a method returning a studentClass[] and have no parameters. Instead, create the studentClass array inside `readStudentData`. I would recommend that approach because it removes the need to create and pass the array, which complicates your main method.

Comment: Thank you, I forgot to add that in but it now lead me to another error that I had before this question also, java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1 specifically on this line     String stuLName = stuArray[1];      I tried various ways to fix it with declaring how many in the stuArray but I then get a syntax error

Comment: Also, yes, regarding the exception handling, I will be adding that later when I finish the code.

Comment: On which line? One thing I notice is `for(int i = 0; i>studentObject.length; i++){` should actually be `for(int i = 0; i<studentObject.length; i++){` (I'll update my answer as well to include this

Comment: Editing it with no parameters actually gives me a syntax error for ' studentObject[i] = new studentClass (stuFName, stuLName, score); ' because "it could not find symbol"

Comment: To do that you have to move declaring and initializing the array into the method or the compiler can't find it.

Comment: Also, I don't think that my earlier comment is actually what's causing the ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException. It is most likely inside `readStudentData`. Are you sure the file actually only has 20 lines of data?

Comment: I just made the required changes and only using the main method with function calling and still with the same error ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException for that line.

Comment: Yes, Duckey Donald 85
Goof Goofy 89
Brave Balto 93
Snow Smitn 93
Alice Wonderful 89
Samina Akthar 85
Simba Green 95
Donald Egger 90
Brown Deer 86
Johny Jackson 95
Greg Gupta 75
Samuel Happy 80
Danny Arora 80
Sleepy June 70
Amy Cheng 83
Shelly Malik 95
Chelsea Tomek 95
Angela Clodfelter 95
Allison Nields 95
Lance Norman 88

Comment: Sorry, I missed the edit on your comment before. That means the stuArray only has 1 element. split() isn't actually splitting. You're going to have to do some debugging on your own here. I would recommend printing the line to the console and seeing what it contains before splitting it.

Comment: Thank you for your input on this, I will keep trying.

Comment: No problem. If you have additional issues I would recommend asking another question